# Which is the last read record by Cosmos change feed processor?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I use a [Cosmos change feed processor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed-processor) to read from my CosmosDb.
How can I, in the lease container, see which is the last read record read?

There are 2 records but I don't understand how it points to a Cosmos record.
If it does at all.

Answer (score 2):

There is no simple way to know, the leases don't point at a particular record, they point at the last point in time you consumed the Change Feed and the Processor checkpointed. So if the Processor would start again (or continue execution), it would look for changes after that last saved Continuation.

You cannot correlate the saved Continuation with a particular document. The leases do have a Timestamp though, so that indicates when was the last saved time, you could use that to have a temporal notion.